# Loop at JSON array and create a single JSON string

Tags: javascript, json, sapui5

This should be easy but for some reason I'm stuck -

if I have a json like this and need to convert it:

```
{ data : [
{id : data1, name : "Description"},
{id : data2, name : "Contribution"},
{id : data3, name : "Footer"},
]}
```

into something like this?

```
 {
data : [
  { data1: "Description" , data2: "Contribution", data3: "Footer" },
  ]}
```

Thanks, 
Stuart

Comment: That's not valid JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small `Array.prototype.reduce` should do the job:

```js
var obj = {
        data: [
            { id: 'data1', name: 'Description' },
            { id: 'data2', name: 'Contribution' },
            { id: 'data3', name: 'Footer' },
        ]
    };

obj.data = obj.data.reduce(function (r, a) {
    r[a.id] = a.name;
    return r;
}, {});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(obj, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `for` loop over the array.

```
var newData = [];

for(var i=0;i<data['data'].length;i++){
    var obj={};
    obj[data['data'][i]['id']]=data['data'][i]['name'];
    newData.push(obj);
}
console.log(newData);
```

Refer [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n57q3vxf/)

**Updated Answer**

```
var newArray = data['data'].map(function(obj){    
   var rObj = {};
   rObj[obj.id] = obj.name;
   return rObj;
});
```

You can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method for that also.

Refer [fiddle-map](http://jsfiddle.net/n57q3vxf/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) lib.

Then check this example for your desired result [Group By](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy)

Enjoy ;-)

Comment: Consider use _.pluck for taking the nedded values before the group by

Answer (score 0):

```
var array=[];
for(int i=0; i<data.length; i++){
var object={};
object[data[i].id=data[i].name];
array.push(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it almost in a single line using [lodash](https://lodash.com/):

```js
var obj1 = { data : [
  {id: "data1", name: "Description"},
  {id: "data2", name: "Contribution"},
  {id: "data3", name: "Footer"},
]};
  
var obj2 = {
  data: _.zipObject(_.pluck(obj1.data, "id"),
                    _.pluck(obj1.data, "name"))
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(obj2, null, 2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

Have a look at [`_.pluck`](https://lodash.com/docs#pluck) and [`_.zipObject`](https://lodash.com/docs#zipObject).
You can also use [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) but lodash is faster, more complete, and you can create custom build with only what you need.